# Appropriate Japan US comparison map

Tags: qgis, comparison, north-america, japan

I would like to create a map in QGIS comparing the relative size and latitudes of Japan to the US. There are a few websites like mapfrappe which allow this using Google Maps, but I would like to be able to have more control over the map settings, projections etc. I like the idea of country comparisons, but I really don't like their execution. My goal is to give a frame of reference for possibly unfamiliar locations. If I discuss Hokkaido, it might be hard to visualize how far north it is, or how large it is. I could provide coordinates and area measurements, but if a large number of areas are discussed, people can start to drown in numbers, where a map or image can quickly provide easy to compare references.

I created an example using the Natural Earth coastline shapefile as a base and dragging the DIV GIS japan admin shapefile over to the east coast of the US (super crappy, but provides a quick visualization). I am not worried about area distortions because I don't want to change any latitude values, but I do want the latitude coordinates to be accurate.[image: bad USA Japan map]

What would be a better way to go about this in QGIS?

Comment: Would using two maps on one composer page qualify as solution?

Comment: As long as the coordinates are accurate the methodology doesn't matter too much to me. Using the composer, how would you do it? I'm guessing one aspect would just be matching up the latitude lines?

Comment: In print composer, make two map frames and set them to the same scale. Turn on a lat/long grid on each map. Turn off the background of each map so the one in front doesn't cover the one in back. Then line them up how you like on the page, making sure the lat/long lines match up.

Comment: @csk you should write this as an answer. It seems perfectly valid.

Comment: @csk That solution worked well enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In print composer, make two map frames and set them to the same scale. Turn on a lat/long grid on each map. Turn off the background of each map so the one in front doesn't cover the one in back. Then line them up how you like on the page, making sure the lat/long lines match up.